# For AWS is there an IAM policy that restricts the user's usage to Free Tier resources only?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

We are planning to grant AWS access to a remote user temporarily to perform a certain task that involves ec2, dynamodb, lambda, api gateway, and cognito. However we want to make sure he won't be going wild and using crazy amount of AWS resources and we ended up having to foot the bill. Is there an IAM policy that restricts a user's usage to Free Tier resources only for all services?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

IAM controls **what API calls can be made**, which includes creating, listing and deleting resources.

However, the [AWS Free Usage Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) is a **billing concept** that overrides the charges for a certain quantity of resources consumed. There is no connection between the two concepts.

You can limit permissions so the user can **only create certain resources** (eg Amazon EC2 t2.micro instances) but there is no capability to restrict it based upon previous resources charged/consumed.

You could create **billing alarms** on the account to receive notification when a certain amount of resources have been consumed, or when it is **forecast** that they will be consumed. These alarms are associated with the **account** rather than a user, so it would require that user to be using a specific account for their own activities.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer, the task is a bit high level so it's hard for us to pre-create the resources and limit the permission for him to create any resource. I guess I will settle with billing alarms for now. Hopefully AWS will implement this feature in the future.

Comment: Please note that resources are associated with an **account**, not a **user**. Therefore, it is unlikely that there would be a feature that can limit spend associated with a _user_. But... innovation keeps happening!

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to setup a [Sandbox OU](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/organizing-your-aws-environment/sandbox-ou.html) (Organizational Unit). Accounts can be created within this OU, which will be collectively constrained by the guardrails (resource limits, quota limits, etc.) setup for this OU.

The overall usage in the Organization may determine whether free-tier billing applies, but you could at least limit usage.

One possible way of keeping in free-tier could be to create a separate organization strictly for onboarding to AWS, with total usage for the Sandbox OU set to remain free-tier.

It is also a good idea to use [CDK](https://aws.amazon.com/cdk/) to deploy things to make it easier to nuke toy projects and not have all sorts of resources provisioned across various services to cleanup.